# OSMNX geocoder returning incorrect coordinates

Tags: python, geocode, osmnx

When using the osmnx geocoder module, it seems that the wrong Latitude and Longitude is returned. I have cross checked the coordinates returned with multiple websites and it is not correct. This is the only relevant code being used:

```
addressList[0] = "7720 N Silverbell Rd, Tucson, Arizona 85743"
address = ox.geocode(addressList[0])
print(address)
```

Which returns: (32.301701, -111.0487101), however when searching on latlong.net, the correct coordinates for this address are (32.347720, -111.096870).

Is there anyway to ensure osmnx returns the correct coordinates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so the answer to your question might be because you are not projecting your Network. Take a look at this similar question I posted which was answered by the creator of the library: [Node found is too far from my lat, lon coordinates (osmnx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829278/node-found-is-too-far-from-my-lat-lon-coordinates-osmnx)

Comment: Thanks, this did not directly solve my issue, but I used the post you linked to find another solution that avoids this issue in general.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to ensure osmnx returns the correct coordinates?

[OSMnx returns](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.geocoder.geocode) whatever the OpenStreetMap [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/) geocoder resolves your query to. You can try to tweak your query or play around with the Nominatim geocoder on the web to see what different queries resolve to.